# How to change images size after theme modification?

Tags: themes, database, images, captions

The images in the previous theme were using a height and width listed in the source html. The new theme will resize the images using percentages, so I need to remove all the height and width in the source html. All images have a specific size.

1. How to remove the height and width when you have an installation with more than 500 posts?
2. How to deal with captions id and size?

Comment: Are you referring to thumbnail/featured images? Or images within the content area?

Comment: I'm referring to images within the content area.

Answer (score 0):

To change values inside the content can you search/replace in the database, but it is hard to update all values, if the values are different. For a search/replace can you use a [plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/) or [helper](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB).

The helper is very good for all ToDos in Search/Replace context. The plugin is useful for search/replace in different tables.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have already installed the plugin. My only issue is how to use the search/replace when it's about removing with and height of images within the posts? My second issue is related to the caption. When removing the height and width of a post the caption does not appear any more.

Comment: The plugin can only replace a string, like `width="123` in `width="456`.

Comment: So that does not solve the problem. The new theme is responsive and in order to work it should not have any picture size specified in the posts.

Comment: You can also replace with percentages values. Alternative kill all width and height values and set via css to right dimension.

Comment: By killing, you mean replacing all width and height values by height="" and width=""?

Comment: Yes, but is a disadvantage for the performance. Google like the values on the img-Tag. But it is easier as change all values manuely.